# Multi item swipedelegate

Tags: qt, qml

Edited due to insufficient intial posting.

Hi,

thanks for your help!

You're right, I guess it is better to include the whole file, in spite of the size:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1
import "./database.js" as Database

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    id: appWindow
    x: Screen.width / 2 - width / 2
    y: Screen.height / 2 - height / 2
    title: qsTr("Project Stats")
    Material.theme: Material.Dark

    ListModel {
        id: projectModel
        ListElement {
            projectID: "123654"
            manager: "Schneider"
            sponsor: "3466"
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: projectDelegate
        SwipeDelegate {
            id: projectSwipeDelegate
            width: parent.width
            height: projectDelegateItem.implicitHeight
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            spacing: 10

            contentItem: Item {
                id: projectDelegateItem
                Text {
                    id: projectID_text
                    text: "Project ID: " + projectID
                    font.pointSize: 20
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    font.weight: Font.Black
                    color: "white"
                }

                Text {
                    id: manager_text
                    text: 'Manager: ' + manager + "  Sponsor: " + sponsor
                    anchors.top: projectID_text.bottom
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    font.weight: Font.Thin
                    color: "lightgrey"
                }
            }


            onClicked: {
                console.log(index, projectModel.get(index).projectID)
                if (swipe.complete)
                    projectModel.remove(index)
                else {
                    //var component= Qt.createComponent("timepointsstackview.qml")
                    //var loadwin = component.createObject(appWindow)
                    //loadwin.selected_project = projectModel.get(index).projectID
                    //                    stackView.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("timepointsstackview.qml"), {properties: {selected_project: projectModel.get(index).projectID}})
                    stackView.push(component, {properties: {selected_project: projectModel.get(index).projectID}})
                }
            }
            swipe.right: Label {
                id: deleteLabel
                text: qsTr("Delete")
                color: "white"
                verticalAlignment: Label.AlignVCenter
                padding: 12
                height: parent.height
                anchors.right: parent.right

                SwipeDelegate.onClicked: projectListView.model.remove(index)

                background: Rectangle {
                    color: deleteLabel.SwipeDelegate.pressed ? Qt.darker("tomato", 1.1) : "tomato"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        Component.onCompleted: {
            Database.getDatabase()
            Database.getProjects()
        }
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        // Implements back key navigation
        focus: true
        Keys.onReleased: if (event.key === Qt.Key_Back && stackView.depth > 1) {
                             stackView.pop();
                             event.accepted = true;
                         }
        initialItem: Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height

            ListView {
                id: projectListView
                anchors.fill: parent
                clip: true

                model: projectModel
                delegate: projectDelegate
            }
        }

    }

    onClosing: {
        if (Qt.platform.os == "android") {
            close.accepted = false;
            //        if (stack.depth > 1) stack.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Meanwhile I already had removed the row/column stuff, which I put in to get it working somehow though I started without it.

I also experimented with implicitheight before intially posting, but sadly to no avail. The above is my current code, though putting in

```
height: projectDelegateItem.implicitHeight
```

in that spot (probabaly not the correct one or the wrong reference? Had to change it from your suggestion as I already took out the row) leads to rendering in one spot only.

Thanks for your time so far and also if you still have the patience to give me a clue where to turn the screws...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. I don't belive you, that this is "the code you got". You probably have some more, like a `ListView` and a `ListModel` that we need to test your code. For future questions, please don't forget those. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to present a good example, we might work with. Others are way more helpful if they can concentrate on your problem, and do not go to great lengths to reproduce your problem first. Though, I hope my answer will help you to tackle and solve your problem. If so, I'd appreciate if you mark it as *accepted* ;-)

Comment: Now you need to give `id`s to both your texts (e.g. `text1` and `text2`). Then you can calculate the height as `height: text1.implicitHeight + text2.implicitHeight`. Greetings :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all:
Take warnings serious. If qml tells you, you should not try to use anchors within rows or columns, don't do it!

> `QML Row: Cannot specify left, right, horizontalCenter, fill or centerIn anchors for items inside Row. Row will not function.`
>
> `QML Column: Cannot specify top, bottom, verticalCenter, fill or centerIn anchors for items inside Column. Column will not function.`

Also don't do it, if you can't see those warnings. It will mess up a lot.
A row automatically anchors all its children side by side to each other. A column does the same, just horizontraly. If you mess with it, everything breaks.

Frankly: I don't even understand why you use this strange Row/Column-Setup.
For your case it seems way better to just resort to anchoring. If you have reasons for that, why not take a grid?

Secondly: You need to specify a height for your delegate. Unfortunately it seems like, it does not calculate an implicit height.
The `SwipeDelegate` calculates its own `implcitHeight` based on the `implicitHeight` of its `contentItem`.

The problem is, that you don't assign the row (which has a proper `implicitHeight`) as **the** `contentItem`, but add it as a child instead.

Assigning it as `contentItem` would fix that for you.

**Regarding your edit, and removal of the Row:** *The `Item` you use now does not calculate a `implicitHeight` based on its children. So you need to provide your calculation yourself.*

This will set a proper height to your delegate, and your delegates won't overlap.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
Window {
    width: 1024
    height: 800
    visible: true

    ListView {
        width: 400
        height: 800

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { projectID: 0; manager: 'I'; sponsor: 'mom' }
            ListElement { projectID: 1; manager: 'YOU'; sponsor: 'dad' }
            ListElement { projectID: 1; manager: 'HE'; sponsor: 'auntie' }
        }

        delegate: SwipeDelegate {
            id: projectSwipeDelegate
            width: parent.width
            // height: <--- provide a height, if the contentItem does not provide it.
            contentItem: Row{ // <--- Add your content as contentItem.
                id: rowProjectDelegate
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                width: parent.width
                Column {
                    id: column
//                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter <--- Don't do that!
                    width: parent.width
                    Rectangle{ // If you don't want to have them in a column, they can't be siblings. If you want to, then you should.
                        height: 10
                        width: 250
                        color: "red"

                        Rectangle {
                            height: 10
                            width: 200
                            color: "blue"
                        }
                    }
                    Label {
                        id: projectID_text
                        text: "Project ID: " + projectID
                        font.pointSize: 20
                        font.weight: Font.Black
                        color: "white"
                    }
                    Label {
                        id: manager_text
                        text: 'Manager: ' + manager + "  Sponsor: " + sponsor
//                        anchors.top: projectID_text.bottom <--- Don't do that!
                        font.weight: Font.Thin
                        color: "lightgrey"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry I had seen the code just after I edited my main post. This works now, I'll just try to factor out the row and column stuff. Bye Joost

Comment: "Unfortunately it seems like, it does not calculate an implicit height." - I'm not so sure about that: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/SwipeDelegate.qml#n47